# ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'greetingsApp.views' (Use multiple app in one project)

Tags: python, django, url, view, importerror

I am beginner in django, simply i tried to use multiple app in one project i got error:

**ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'greetingsApp.views'**

project description:

```
/thirdProject
     /greetingsApp
         /views.py
              from django.http import HttpResponse
                   def greetings_view(arg):
                        return HttpResponse('<h1> Good Morning....</h1>')
     /timeApp
         /views.py
              from django.http import HttpResponse
              import datetime
                     def time_view(arg):
                         time = datetime.datetime.now()
                         save = '<h1> Current Server timr'+str(time)+'</h1>'
                         return HttpResponse(save)
    /thirdProject
         /urls.py
              from django.contrib import admin
              from django.urls import path
              from greetingsApp.views import views as v1
              from timeApp.views import views as v2
              urlpatterns = [
                        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                        path('greetings/', v1.greetings_view),
                        path('time/', v2.time_view),
                        ]
         /settings.py
              INSTALLED_APPS = [
                   'django.contrib.admin',
                    ........
                    'greetingsApp',
                    'timeApp',
```

**Run:** `F:\djangoProject\thirdProject>py manage.py runserver`

**Error:**

```
File "F:\djangoProject\thirdProject\thirdProject\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from greetingsApp.views import views as v1
ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'greetingsApp.views' (F:\djangoProject\thirdProject\greetingsApp\views.py)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Seems like you are using `from greetingsApp.views import views`; Try `from greetingsApp import views`

Comment: Is your problem solved? If so, please [consider marking the answer as acceptet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or add more information if you problem wasn't solved yet.

Answer (score 1):

These two lines are your problem:

```
from greetingsApp.views import views as v1
from timeApp.views import views as v2
```

You want to import `views` from inside of `views.py` and since there is no function `views` in that, you can't import it.

What you want to do is the following:

```
from greetingsApp import views as v1
from timeApp import views as v2
```